# How to make the Facebook webapp work without keeping Firefox open?

Tags: webapps, facebook

I want to have notifications of Facebook on the envelop letter of Ununtu desktop (I know I'm not using the correct names, but I've been using Ubuntu since a week).

I looked up for programs like Fbuntu but is not working in 12.10. I installed the web app, but it only shows me the chat and notifications when Facebook is open with the browser (Firefox).

Can't I see that information when Firefox is closed? Or does there exist any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

In this method you can only see who are all on-line and you can just chat with them. By using Empathy which will installed by default in your Ubuntu version. Press super key ( windows logo key ) and type empathy. Once you open empathy press f4 and click on add button in the left. You will find so many accounts like gmail, facebook, yahoo etc. Add all accounts which you want to by providing their respective username and password.

To see some more good results for facebook goto software center which will be present in launcher and search for emesene(another facebook messenger). You will also find so many other softwares. Ask if have missed anything you want.

**Updated**:

It has been mentioned that it(jfbchat) provides voice notification but i don't know really weather they are notification of facebook or notification of message. Follow this link to install jfbchat "http://handytutorial.com/install-facebook-chat-client-in-ubuntu-12-04-windows-7/". Give it a try.

Comment: thanks for your answer! i saw empathy but i doesn't work with notifications. Also serched in the Software Center, and nothing.. thanks again anyway!

Comment: See the updated part in the answer. Thats the only messenger near to your requirement.

Comment: Downloaded jfbchat (from other link, that one didn't work), althought i couldn't sing in in it, i saw the preferences and it didn't show anything relative to notifications.. i guess i'll have to wait something like Fbuntu for Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: may be yes. I hope you have not used your email-id as you use in browser. Because before signing in you cannot configure any notification options.

Comment: it seems that it's a disregarded website.. when you try to create an account it doesn't appears the captcha wich is a requiriment for suscription.. so i could't try JFBChat